# Global Object in singleton

Tags: c++, singleton

In the Singleton pattern why is that we have to use a static object and not a global object?

I tried the following

```
class Singleton;
Singleton*  instance1 = NULL;

class Singleton
{
private :
       Singleton()
       {
       }
       //static Singleton* instance1;

public:
        static Singleton* getinstance()

 if(instance1== NULL)
       {
       instance1 = new Singleton();
       }

 return instance1;


 void Dispaly()
       {
       }
 ~Singleton()
       {
       }
};
```

When I compile this code I get the error "multiple definition of instance1"

Can anyone please give a plausible reason for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern

Comment: @Jan: that will give you a separate instance in each translation unit, not a single instance for the whole program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make it a global object, then everyone has access to it, and anyone can use it without calling `getInstance()`. If so, then what is the purpose of `getInstance()` then? First time, you will call it to create the instance, then you wouldn't be required to call `getInstance()`, since after the first call, you can directly use `instance`.

A `private` *static* instance gives you more control how it can be accessed: only through by calling `getInstance()`.

Now why you get `multiple definition of instance` error when compiling your code? Its because you've defined the global object in the header file itself, which is included in multiple `.cpp` files. This causes multiple definitions of the object, one definition in each translation unit (.`obj`  file).

What you actually should be doing is this:

```
//Singleton.h
class Singleton
{
private :
        Singleton();
        Singleton(const Singleton &);
       ~Singleton();

        static Singleton* instance; //declaration of static member!

public:
        static Singleton* getInstance();
       //..
};
```

And then define the `static` member in the `.cpp` file as:

```
//Singleton.cpp
 Singleton *Singleton::instance = 0; //definition should go in .cpp file!

 Singleton::Singleton() {}

 Singleton* Singleton::getInstance()
 {
     if ( instance  == 0 ) instance  = new Singleton();
     return instance;
 }
 //...
```

Comment: I agree with your point.
I am just asking why is it giving compilation error on including global object inside a static function...

Answer (score 4):

To answer your direct question:

The reason you get the error message is because you are defining a variable in a header file (well, that's my guess, anyway).  So every time you `#include` that header file, the variable will get re-defined.

In summary, there's almost never a good reason for defining variables in header files.

*[Side note: as others have explained, this is a very bad implementation of the singleton pattern.]*

Comment: Yes You were right.
Now my original question.
why do we need static object and why cant we just use a global object?

Comment: You CAN use a global object... but why would you? What's the purpose of your class then, if you can just get your object directly?

Answer (score 3):

If you include this header in multiple files, you will get a copy of the pointer in each file.

That's probably what the linker is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad singleton implementation. You should use an implementation which is already here. There are a lot of them.. and your error will disappear.

For example, someone can set `instance = NULL;`. Doing that you can instantiate more than one instance.

Comment: Yeah I know this is not perfect.This is just some test code.
My question is just why is it giving compilation error on having a global object inside static function?

Comment: That's not an answer to the question. It should probably be a comment. Here was the question: *"When I compile this code I get the error "multiple definition of instance1" Can anyone please give a plausible reason for this?"*

Answer (score 0):

That defeats the purpose of the singleton - accessing the object from a single place. You can access it everywhere without having to call getInstance().

As for the error, my guess is you included your header in multiple files.

Put

```
#pragma once
```

at the beginning of your header file, that should solve the error.

But again, this is a bad implementation of the singleton pattern.

EDIT:

Or use header guards:

```
#ifndef _SINGLETON_CLASS_INCLUDED
#define _SINGLETON_CLASS_INCLUDED

//// contents of your header

#endif
```

Comment: Header guards will prevent multiple inclusion in a single translation unit, but won't prevent inclusion in multiple translation units, which will still give the error. Also, you shouldn't use reserved names for the header guards.

Comment: Agreed: Pragmas and header guards won't help here.

Answer (score 0):

Put the definition of instance1 in a cpp file and an extern in the header.

It would be more typical to use a static class member though, as you have commented out.
You just need to define it in a cpp file:

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance1 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

> In the Singleton pattern why is that we have to use a static object
>   and not a global object?

Static object is private member of your class and nobody has access to it except Singleton class. This is basic **encapsulation** principle in C++ and other OOP languages.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is part of a header file, then you'll get one definition of `instance1` for each translation unit that includes it, and so a multiple definition error if more than one includes it. You'll get this problem whether it's a global or a static member.

To fix the error, you need a declaration in the header file (`extern Singleton * instance1;` if you want it to be global for some reason, or a private static member declaration if you want to prevent arbitrary access to it), and then a definition in a source file.

Alternatively, you could make the instance a static local object in `getinstance()`, which will fix the memory leak and, in C++11 at least, the thread safety problem:

```
static Singleton & getinstance()
{
    static Singleton instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Or you could not use a singleton at all - it's almost certainly not a good idea.